# How to save customer_address custom attribute from checkout onepage

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-address

I have created a custom customer_address attribute using below script  :

```
$installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('customer_address', 'country_code', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Country Code',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1
));
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer_address', 'country_code')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_register_address','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address'))
    ->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

and added it in billing.phtml as :

```
<input type="text" name="billing[country_code]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCountryCode()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Country Code')) ?>" class="input-text  required-entry " id="billing:country_code"  />
```

But on order place other values saved in customer address but not custom attribute.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow this article 
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/29/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address/ , especially the last part with 
`Checkout Billing/Shipping Step`. Even if the article its a little bit old I think its still allright also for Magento 1.9. 


The most important part is that you should also add this custom attribute also on the `sales/quote_address` and `sales/order_address` entities in order to have data persistence. And you should also add some extra stuff in the `config.xml` file.

I hope it helps!